# When should we define functions on an object's prototype vs. in the object itself?

Tags: javascript

Specifically, I don't understand why some methods require a `.prototype` in front of them but others to not. I was practising a code where a correct answer was

```
var Foo = function(value) {
  this.val = value;
}

Foo.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.val;
}
```

and I am wondering why the prototype in `Foo.prototype.valueOf` was needed, why can you not simply just do `Foo.valueOf`? It is what I did before with other prototypes. For example, I do `x.slice(2,4)` and not `x.prototype.slice(2,4).`

Comment: Before anything could be explained about this, you should first understand the difference between **adding/setting a method** and **calling an already existing method.**

Comment: Short answer: You can! Both work and are valid JavaScript

Long answer: The .prototype way is a preferred way of defining *methods* for an object *constructor* because in that way, all methods are shared between instances created with that constructor instead of being redefined each time, which would be somewhat more memory intensive (and might have a performance benefit in modern browsers, who tend to search for methods first in an object's prototype).

Comment: the valueOf() drills into the object to return just the val property instead of the whole object.

Comment: If you'd like to know more about how prototype is used by JavaScript then the following answer may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foo` is a constructor function. If you wanted to call `Foo.valueOf` like `x.slice`, you could set `Foo.valueOf`, but that’s not what this code accomplishes; it says that any object *constructed* using `Foo` should inherit the `valueOf` defined there. So:

```
var x = new Foo(42);
x.valueOf() === 42 // true
```